# How to secure QR code to be valid for specific user only for 24hrs

Tags: php, qr-code

I need your help in as per subject securing QR code but under below terms.

- QR code will be available for scan by Hotel room guest.
- Each room will have different QR code
- QR code should be avalieble/accessible 24hrs only unless you scan again as a guest

Now my question here is about idea, how do I can secure it so somebody who will take picture of this QR code and try accessing it from home or elsewhere will get access denied.

This is purely advice and option search topic here, I am not asking for codes examples etc.

I was thinking about having system to generate new tokens for each room every 24hrs which is fine and durable but I am lacking to understand how I can then check this and with what?

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: you could make **cronjob** that update all code for each room every 24 hour

Comment: Yeah that is what I am thinking about but my problem is, if you take picture of that QR code and you scan it at home, then you could access it again?

Comment: no it should not be found anymore after 24 hours from creation

Comment: or to be more secure change the QRCODE after each scan, for example, the guest of room 7 scan a code in his room update this code after scanning and so on

Comment: And this is the bit I dont get when you access QR code it will go to something like room_app.php?room_id=$roomID&room_token=$room_token then it will read this cron token generated every 24 hrs so how come I can stop this process from being followed again by user from elsewhere?

Comment: Generating code everyday in each room will not work.

Comment: did you check the last comment about changing the code after each scan?

Comment: Yes those will be printed QR codes Joseph so printing it everyday makes no sense.

Comment: aha is this code printed manual in papers!! in this case it isn't make sence

Comment: Yes but there must be a way. I was also thinking about geolocation maybe? but if I can I would like to avoid this

Comment: what about checking if this user connects from the hotel network? if he connects from a hotel let him to scan the code otherwise give it access denied i think it would be good and simple

Comment: yes that is also an option unless there is any other options. maybe others will have different ideas. Thank you Joseph

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to choose to ask for localisation confirmation before the app could be opened. It's not ideal but should give me maximum of what I am trying to achieve.